# Why CSS and Bootstrap elements disappear with node express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I firstly made a basic node server like this:

```
  var connect = require('connect');

  var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
  connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('Server running on 8080...');
  });
```

Then I replaced it with an express server like this:

```
   var express = require("express");
   var app     = express();
   var path    = require("path");

   app.get('/',function(req,res){
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));

   });

   app.use(express.static("public"));

   app.listen(8080);

   console.log("Running at Port 8080");
```

With the first one, everything worked fine. CSS, JQuery, images etc..., but with the second one, some of my style elements totally disappeared and it can't reach the pictures on the site. What did I miss? How can I solve it?

Comment: You're just serving the index.html, you still need to server static files in express. https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not serving static files.

```
app.use(express.static("public"))
```

This would serve all files from `/public` directly on the root of your server `/`. If you want to serve them at `/static` you need to modify the code a bit.

```
app.use("/static", express.static("public"))
```

### Example

#### File Structure

```
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── public
| └ style.css
|
└── server.js
```

#### server.js

```
var express = require("express")
var app = express()

app.use(express.static("public"))

app.listen(3333)
```

After running server.js you should be able to access http://localhost:3333/style.css (and every other file in the /public directory)

Comment: It doesn't work :( I know it should but it has no effect. I refreshed my code with you line. I made a pulbic folder, and put the data into it.

Comment: Have a look at my template repo [here](https://github.com/0Skynet/Node-WebApp-Template) it might help you. You are probably just messing up the folder structure or the `<link rel...` stuff in html, just check your html and try to access the .css and .js files directly.

Comment: I don't think I have problems with my html structure. It's just simply not working. I 've installed and saved express, made a reference in server.js with one line what should make every folder public. It should be that easy. I'm a little upset because it is a basic thing, and I can't make it work. In your repo before the css folder you have "public/" with lightgrey. I'd need that too :D

Comment: Just click on "clone or download" then "download zip" and have a look at the folder structure and compare it to your folder structure. If that looks correct compare the `href` attribute of my `<link>` inside of `home.pug` to your `href` attributes and make sure you can actually access your resources.

Comment: That damn filestructure.. Now it finally works. Thank you for your persistence :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to serve static files have a look at https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html which shows you can use:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.static('files'))
```

to serve static files from the `public` and `files` folder. In your example code you are only serving the `index.html`.

Comment: I'm trying but it's not working for now. So I have to create a folder, named static, put all the content into it, and after that use this code snippet: app.use(express.static('public')) in the server.js file.

Comment: No, you just create a folder any name you want. In my example I used `public` and `files` as folder names. As long as you call the `express.static` method with your folder name